# How to get vue treeselect value

Tags: forms, vue.js

I implemented Vue-Treeselect on my website, everything is ok, a have treeselect with my records. The problem is - how to get value of selected items?

My implementation:

head:

```
    <!-- include Vue 2.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2"></script>
    <!-- include vue-treeselect & its styles. you can change the version tag to better suit your need. -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riophae/vue-treeselect@0.0.29/dist/vue-treeselect.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riophae/vue-treeselect@0.0.29/dist/vue-treeselect.min.css">
```

App section (inside form):

```
                                         <div id="app">
                                          <treeselect v-model="value" :multiple="true" :options="options" placeholder="Wybierz region..."/>
                                         <input type="hidden" name="location" value="{{ value }}" />

                                         <div class="result">{{ value }}</div>

                                    </div>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
// register the component
Vue.component('treeselect', VueTreeselect.Treeselect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // define default value
    value: [],
    // define options
    options: [ 

                                                <?
                                                    $sql = mysql_query("select * from kody group by woj");
                                                    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                                                ?>
                                                { id: '<?echo $data['woj'];?>',
                                                  label: '<?echo $data['woj'];?>',
                                                  children: [ 

                                                        <?
                                                            $sql1 = mysql_query("select * from kody where woj like '".$data['woj']."' group by powiat");
                                                            while($data1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
                                                                ?>
                                                                {
                                                                id: '<?echo $data['woj'];?>-<? echo $data1['powiat'];?>',
                                                                label: '<? echo $data1['powiat'];?>',                                                                       
                                                                },

                                                        <?
                                                            }
                                                        ?>

                                                    ]
                                                },

                                                <?
                                                    }
                                                ?>



    ],
  },
})
```

I have treeselect with my records, I can select it, but I can't use it in, f.e. get request with other form elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your:

```
<treeselect v-model="value" ... />
```

add a name="..." parameter like so:

```
<treeselect name="xyz" v-model="value" ... />
```

and it will create a hidden form field for the value.

You can find the property buried in the documentation under the props section: https://vue-treeselect.js.org/